# Rails jQuery Mobile convert string to time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails 4.0.0 time format fields for start time and finish time. I want to use the jQuery Mobile DateBox which formats the time like '02:41 AM'. How can I convert this string to a time field in Rails. My database is Postgresql.

migratiuon:

```
  t.time :start_time, :null => false
  t.time :finish_time, :null => false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to forget about the jQuery time picker as the plain Rails time_selector looks pretty good. One issue I had with it was that it outputs two select options fields with a colon (:) in between them. This colon prevented data-type="horizontal" from displaying inline. The solution is as below. Furthermore, omitting ignore_date on a time field results in a Multiparameter out of range error.

```
<div>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <legend>Start Time</legend>
  <%= f.time_select :start_time, time_separator: "", ignore_date: true, ampm: true %>
  </fieldset>   
</div>
```